# How to reduce size of tessdata used for TessBaseAPI in android?

Tags: android, tesseract

I have an android application where I am using Tesseract OCR i.e the TessBaseAPI.
This requires tessdata which is 21mb file. My final app release APK comes to approx 19 mb which I find quite a lot.
Is there any way by which I can reduce the size of tessdata or my app or anything else which will help me reduce the final APK size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [3.01](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/) version of `.trainddata` files -- they have much smaller size -- which are still compatible with newer versions of Tesseract.

Comment: I found negligible difference in my samples, but you certainly can test for more definitive comparisons.