# How to avoid using OpenCV unused methods in android while generating APK output

Tags: android, opencv

I have an application that use OpenCV for image proccessing, everything works well, but most size of my android output APK file is for OpenCV component. As I do not use most of source codes of OpenCV for my app, am I able to avoid using all of OpenCV methods?

Comment: You could attempt to build the library yourself and only include the dependencies that you require

Answer (score 0):

[how to reduce android app size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109777/how-to-reduce-android-app-size)
I reduce my app size from the above accepted answer. You can just split your apk for different processors according to your jnilibs.