# Reduce apk size and apk data size when using OCR Android

Tags: android, zip, apk, ocr

I am using [OCR project](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr)  in my app project.I have added two zip file `eng.traineddata.zip(12.1MB)` and `osd.traineddata.zip(4.1MB)` and implemented library `jtar-1.0.4.jar(12.1kb)`.

I have use some classes of [OCR project](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr). In this project for character reorganization when open camera they are extracting from `eng.traineddata.zip(12.1MB)` and `osd.traineddata.zip(4.1MB)` files from assets folder and save in Internal storage.

Now my debug apk size is 38.6MB on installation and when open camera from this app data will be 47.28MB.My app not depending on Internet and not want to extracting these both zip files from Internet.

I want to reduce apk size and apk data size.I am not using ndk.How to do this?
Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe Proguard has some options for discarding unused classes etc.. I know it has cut a smaller project's APK size by almost a half for me.

Comment: I already done that.

Comment: Try my suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36122110).

Comment: Sir..@rmthesis plese check my edited question.

Comment: If added split in build.gradle then my apk size reduce to 21.5MB. but its create app-dev-x86-debug.apk. Is it run on any devices? and if i remove those two zip file from assets folder and extracting from Internet then its reduce size to 5.4MB. But i don't want to use Internet in my app and want to generate apk for all devices.Then splits apk work for me?