# Reduce apk size and apk data size when using OCR Character Android

Tags: android, ocr

I am using OCR project in my app project.I have added two zip file eng.traineddata.zip(12.1MB),chi_tra.traineddata.zip(30.1MB) and osd.traineddata.zip(4.1MB) and implemented library jtar-1.0.4.jar(12.1kb).

I have use some classes of OCR project. In this project for character reorganization when open camera they are extracting from eng.traineddata.zip(12.1MB) and osd.traineddata.zip(4.1MB) files from assets folder and save in Internal storage.

Now my debug apk size is 50.6MB on installation and when open camera from this app data will be 63.28MB.My app not depending on Internet and not want to extracting these both zip files from Internet.

Comment: Have you tried using ProGuard?

Comment: yes, i am using chineese traditional language for OCR

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reduce android app size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109777/how-to-reduce-android-app-size)